# Pager not found Jqgrid error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I am trying to integrate jqgrid in my application, but i'm getting pager not found error.

Here are the imports.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Scripts/themes/steel/grid.css" title="steel" media="screen" />
    <link href="/Scripts/themes/jqModal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/Scripts/Lib/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>  
        <script src="/Scripts/Lib/jquery.blockUI.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/Lib/jquery.bgiframe.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>  



    <script src="/Scripts/Lib/js/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/Lib/jquery.jqGrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/Lib/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/Lib/js/jqModal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/Lib/js/jqDnR.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is my .htm file

```
<body>
<div id="report-tab">
<h2>Customers List</h2>
    <table id="list" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    </table>
     <div id="pager"></div>

    </div>
    </body>
```

Here is my report.js file code

```
var ReportTab = function () {

    return {
        Init: function () {

            // jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            var test = $('#list');
            var Pager1 = $('#pager');
            test.jqGrid({
                Url: "/Home/GridData",
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'GET',
                colNames: ['Id', 'Votes', 'Title'],
                colModel: [
          { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 40, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'Votes', index: 'Votes', width: 40, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'Title', index: 'Title', width: 200, align: 'left'}],
                pager : $('#pager'),
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
                sortname: 'Id',
                sortorder: "desc",
                viewrecords: true,
                imgpath: '/scripts/themes/steel/images',
                caption: 'My first grid'
            }).navGrid(pager, { edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: true, search: false });
            //  });
        }
    }
} ();
```

Help in fixing the issue

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Separate out your pager at the bottom - Rather then

```
navGrid(pager, { edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: true, search: false });
```

try

```
$('#list').jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: true, search: false});
```

It might come down to the way you look for the "pager" as shown in the first line, you could also try indicating what is the pager by '#pager' vs pager.